# Do Java Swing action on specified Date

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, date, timer

I'm trying to create a program which has two options:
 - Do specific task after countdown (in minutes).
 - Do specific task on the date selected.
 Both are using jSpinners however, I don't know how to do the action on the specific date, here's the code below, thank you in advance!

```
protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
           Timer t = new Timer(0,  new ActionListener() {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               }
           });

           //Checking state of CheckBoxes (one cancels the other)
               if(jCheckBox2.isSelected()) {
               try {
                   int delay =(int) jSpinner2.getValue();
                   jCheckBox1.setSelected(false);
                       Thread.sleep(delay*60000); //To delay the code from miliseconds to minutes
                   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                       Logger.getLogger(App_Gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
   ex);
                   }
           }
               else if (jCheckBox1.isSelected()) {
                   Date delay2 = (Date) jSpinner1.getValue();
                   jCheckBox2.setSelected(false);
                   Thread.sleep(delay2); //What should I put here instead of Thread.sleep()???????

       }

           //If all is right, start the timer
           t.start();       
        t.setRepeats(false);
           //Popup dialog
           JDialog dialog = new JDialog();     
          dialog.setLocation(700, 300);
          dialog.setSize(600, 400);  
          dialog.setVisible(true);
          //Speed of color changing
          try {

             Thread.sleep(jSlider1.getValue());
                     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(App_Gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
   ex);
           } //Setting the color
          dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(jLabel2.getBackground());

        dialog.setModal(true);
        Assignment_Tajmer_Aplikacija.f.setVisible(false);    

        return null;
       }
       protected void done() {
           System.out.println("Done!");
       }
        };
        sw.execute();



       }                                        

       private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
           // TODO add your handling cosadde here:
           jSlider1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
           JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
           //System.out.println(source.getValue());

         }
       });
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

1. You compute time difference in milliseconds between current date and target date. So you can start the swing timer. Something like `myDate.getTime() - Sytem.currentTimeMillis()` (it's probably not always correct)
2. You use a Library which do it for you (for example [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)). In this case you need to synchronize your job with the Swing thread using the method `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`.

And never use `Thread.sleep()` in a Swing application. Start a timer instead.